# jQuery validation plugin shows validation message too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, forms

I have a search form where different groups of checkboxes are shown depending on what the user chooses in a drop-down. I want to use jQuery validation plugin to check that the user has (a) chosen something in the drop-down, and (b) checked at least one checkbox.

I've gotten this to work, except that the validation message for the checkboxes is behaving strangely. The user can choose a value in the drop-down without problems, but as the user clicks **anything** on the page (even an empty area), the validation error message for the checkboxes is displayed. Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Here is my JS code for the validation plugin. I chose to have the all validation messages show up next to the drop-down (which has name='to'), rather than next to the checkboxes (which all have class='from_checkbox').

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Method for verifying that at least one checkbox has been checked
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("atLeastOneChecked", function(value, element, params) { 
        return $('.from_checkbox:checked').length > 0; 
    }, jQuery.format("From?"));

    // Tell jQuery validation plugin to validate the search form with the proper rules
    $("#search_form").validate({
        rules: {
            'to': { 
                required: true, 
                atLeastOneChecked: true
            }
        }, 
        messages: {
            'to': {
                required: "To?"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Much of the html is generated by php, but the output looks something like this:

```
<form action="results.php" method="post" id="search_form">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Destination</td>
            <td>
                <select name="to" onchange='changeFromDiv(options[selectedIndex].value)'>
                    <option disabled="disabled" selected value="">--select--</option>
                    <option value="1">Country 1</option>
                    <option value="2">Country 2</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" id="from_label">Which cities can you travel from?</td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div style="display:none" class="from_div" id="from_1">
                    <input name="from[3]" type="checkbox" value="3" class="from_checkbox" /> City 3<br />
                    <input name="from[4]" type="checkbox" value="4" class="from_checkbox" /> City 4<br />
                    <input name="from[8]" type="checkbox" value="8" class="from_checkbox" /> City 8<br />
                </div>
                <div style="display:none" class="from_div" id="from_2">
                    <input name="from[1]" type="checkbox" value="1" class="from_checkbox" /> City 1<br />
                    <input name="from[6]" type="checkbox" value="6" class="from_checkbox" /> City 6<br />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Find best route" onclick="showLoading()" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Just edited the question to include the html. If you'd like to see any other code (such as the JS for showing and hiding the divs with the checkboxes), please just let me know and I'll include it.

Comment: The validation plugin normally checks fields when they lose focus, right?  That is, when you click anywhere else on the page, exactly as you describe.  It's working as intended, I bet.

Comment: Oooh! I didn't realize that. Do you know if there's a way to have it wait until the user clicks the submit button?

Comment: See my answer - I *think* that's all you have to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialize the plugin, just include a setting for the "onfocusout" option:

```
$("#search_form").validate({
    rules: {
        'to': { 
            required: true, 
            atLeastOneChecked: true
        }
    }, 
    messages: {
        'to': {
            required: "To?"
        }
    },
    onfocusout: false
});
```

That will tell the plugin not to perform validation checks on the "blur" events from elements involved.  It'll wait until the form is submitted.  There's also an "onkeyup" flag, which probably isn't relevant to you since you're not working with text inputs.

Comment: Glad to have been awake enough to help!